# How can I power a kinect using the iRobot Create 2 base? (Turtlebot)

Tags: ros, kinect, sensor, create2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone!

I'm creating a turtlebot from scratch. I have an iRobot Create 2, a kinect sensor (and all its cables), and an acer netbook.

How do I provide 12V power to the kinect using the create 2? I saw a lot of tutorials online and they say to use the serial port on the create 2 base. However, if I do this, then how do I connect the create 2 to my netbook?

Currently I am using the serial to USB cable to connect the irobot to my netbook. Is there a way to splice this cable and use it for powering the kinect?

Or will I need an external 12V battery?

Thanks! I'm relatively new to electronics, so any help is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236239/how-can-i-power-a-kinect-using-the-irobot-create-2-base?-(turtlebot)/) by [blazerman345](https://answers.ros.org/users/27088/blazerman345/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

iRobot has published instructions about getting power from the Create 2's internal battery [here](http://www.irobotweb.com/%7E/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/BatteryPower.pdf?la=en). The Kinect can be powered by the main brush motor driver, you just have to regulate it down to 12V. They recommend using an inductor but I did not end up needing one. You just have to send power to the main brush motor when you start up your turtlebot, which is opcode 144 of the Create 2 open interface.

---

Originally posted by [Raika](https://answers.ros.org/users/28049/raika/) with karma: 18 on 2016-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0